# Views Criteria Filter - Changes Affect Master Display

Tags: views

I have a problem with the module `Views` with the `FILTER CRITERIA`, When I clone a block inside my view and change the `FILTER CRITERIA` the change also occurs on the `Master Display` is it a normal behavior ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the default behaviour. But you can change it easily.

When you're editing the filters in your cloned display, look to the top of the dialog. You'll see a select list like this:

[image]

That select list determines whether the changes you're about to make are applied to the whole view, or just the display you're working on. If you choose "This xxx" (where xxx could be any number of things like page, etc), the changes you save will not apply to the other displays.

Comment: hi Clive! have a nice day :P